# Failing to add liquidity to pancakeswap on bsc testnet

Tags: bsc, pancakeswap, binance, liquidity-provider

Here is the error message.

```
Fail with error 'PancakeRouter: EXPIRED'
```

[Here is the transaction details](https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x5c449b87f766c9fd09b300e43d1c5794523f9f8ad97dc6808654d017845e7dcd)

I suspect its because of the deadline attribute? I have no clue on how to do a  `block.timestamp` , so I try to time it by checking when is the "nearest" blocktime from https://testnet.bscscan.com/block/countdown/

Does anyone know why im getting this error, and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe this problem is due to the `deadline` parameter of the addLiquidity method.

In your tx you have submitted a deadline of `7741799` which corresponds (https://www.epochconverter.com/) to `Tuesday, March 31, 1970 2:29:59 PM`

You can go to the pancakeswap router contract (https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xd99d1c33f9fc3444f8101754abc46c52416550d1) and successful transactions that use this method, such as https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x6b5f2c486dcfb6f2c40410242e8e63360d2b374a13545e2cda70063e7c444e5f.

In this tx you see the `deadline` is `1672491599` corresponding to `Saturday, December 31, 2022 12:59:59 PM` which ahead of the time when this transaction was processed.

Comment: Hey man thanks for the comment, I changed the deadline but im having another error: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED , do you have any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: did you find any solutions?

Comment: @Burak unfortunately, not yet, do you have any clue?

Comment: @neowenshun, in order to solve `TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED` I had to approve the amount I want to use from my contract. In the approve function, use the router's address and your desired amount. After, I used `addLiquidityETH` from the router's contact and it worked like a charm!

Comment: That's weird, i tried this as well but it still does not work. It clearly says from the allowance method that i had granted the router the desired amount to spend

Comment: Hey @Burak I think my issue was that i did not approve the transaction on BNB side, may i ask how you were able to do it? I can't find the contract address for BNB

Comment: @neowenshun, I believe if you can follow this you can solve it. https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/cant-add-liquidity-on-pancakeswap-with-burnable-erc20-token/6993/10